# How to call findResults on a varargs variable

Tags: groovy

I've been coding Groovy for about 3 days now (coming from Python) and am a bit baffled about varargs .

I have this:

```groovy
def wtf(Integer ...vals) {
  println vals.getClass()
  filtered = vals.findResults{ it > 4 ? it : null }
}

wtf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

which produces:

```
class [Ljava.lang.Integer;
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.Integer;.findResults() is applicable for argument types: (Script1$_wtf_closure1) values: [Script1$_wtf_closure1@5bcf875d]
Possible solutions: findResult(groovy.lang.Closure), findResult(java.lang.Object, groovy.lang.Closure)
```

So it seems that my `val` vararg is of a type that doesn't have the `findResults` method.

From docs http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html it seems that the method comes from `Collection` which sounds like a fairly general base class for list-like object.

So... what is the type of the vararg?  It seems to be `[Ljava.lang.Integer` but I'm not sure exactly what that means in Groovy terms. Why is it giving me a useless type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Ljava.lang.Integer
```

is an Array of Integer in Java's naming...  (ie:  a `Integer[]`)

So you just need to get it into a list:

```
def wtf(Integer ...vals) {
    filtered = vals.toList().findResults{ it > 4 ? it : null }
}
```

Comment: Doh I thought I'd tried that! What I actually tried was `vals = vals.toList(); vals.findResults{ ... }` ...this gives the original error, which seems mean that the first line fails silently. Groovy WTF?

Comment: But by that time, you've already dictated to Groovy that the type of `vals` is `Integer[]`, so it probably changes the array into a List, then changes it back into an array to store it in `vals`...  If you'd declared wtf as `def wtf(...vals)` it should have worked

Comment: Ah I see!  `def wtf(...vals)` doesn't seem to work though

Comment: You're right `def wtf(...vals)` doesn't work :-(  Sorry about that :-(

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I guess it's not very fruitful to ponder why Groovy was designed the way it is.

```
def wtf(Integer ...vals) {
  filtered = (vals as Collection).findResults{ it > 4 ? it : null }
  println filtered
}

wtf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

> Result: [5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Arrays are not collections in Java, that's where the issue lies

Comment: hmm, this shouldn't have been so surprising, from reading now it seems Array is a fixed-size collection, so more analogous to Python's tuple (vs mutable list) which is what you get from `*args` too. thanks for your help